# Mobile performance down

Tags: apache-flex, mobile

I made an test mobile application with some buttons only (say 40). When I press a button I push another view. This is all. But, when I run into mobile (android in this case) and press a button, it takes like 3 seconds or more to start to go to another screen. Whats the problem? Why is this so slow?

Comment: I think you're going to need to post some code

Comment: I second the "show code" comment.  Without knowing what the next view is doing; it's tough to help you optimize.

Comment: There is nothing to show. Just add a lot of buttons to a view and call another using them. This is too slow.

Comment: What kind of buttons do you have? What kind of android device do you have? Are you testing in debug mode?

Comment: default spark buttons, not in debug mode.

Comment: I've tested your scenario on my phone. It takes about 0.2 seconds to generate and add 40 buttons. View switching takes about 0.5 seconds(I've disabled animation). Nothing near 3 seconds. Can you tell more details? Any images on your buttons?

Comment: Flex components are known to be slow for instantiation and attaching. I think you see expected behavior. If you want to improve performance try: precreate in background and use simple layout (Basic). Adobe list can be used to render only part of visible components

Comment: @Fabricio did you got the reason why your app was so slow? How did you fix this?